# SciChart Format values on individual FastLineRenderableSeries for WPF, Xamarin.Android, and Xamarin.IOS

Tags: wpf, charts, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, scichart

I have found examples on how to format values by applying a format to an axis, but i need to format each line that is applied to the same axis differently. The issue is that i will chart a point with a YValue of 100.5 but the cursor modifier will show 100.5xxxxx where x is a random decimal. So i need to be able to format these values by applying a format to the line itself and not the axis.

Answer (score 1):

In SciChart there is the concept of TextFormatting and CursorTextFormatting. This is described in the [documentation for SciChart.iOS](https://www.scichart.com/documentation/ios/v2.x/Axis%20Labels%20-%20TextFormatting%20and%20CursorTextFormatting.html) and [SciChart.Android](https://www.scichart.com/documentation/android/v2.x/Axis%20Labels%20-%20TextFormatting%20and%20CursorTextFormatting.html)

**iOS**

> **Axis CursorTextFormatting**
>
> The AxisCore.CursorTextFormatting property defines how text is formatted for cursor labels which appear on the axis. To change the CursorTextFormatting, use a standard NSString formatting string as follows:
>
> ```
> // TextFormatting of cursor labels on SCINumericAxis to show two decimal places
> var axis = new SCINumericAxis();
> axis.CursorTextFormatting = "%.02f";
> ```

**Android**

> **Axis Overlays Formatting**
>
> Axis API allows to assign a formatting string for axis overlays, such as Cursor axis labels. Similarly to axis labels formatting, there is the setCursorTextFormatting() method for this. Likewise, it **uses the same Java Format** API internally, so everything aforementioned applies to the cursor labels as well.
>
> ```
> yAxis.setCursorTextFormatting("'Price:'###.##' $'");
> ```

Remember that SciChart's Xamarin charts are a wrapper of the native iOS/Android charts, so the string formats are not .NET formats, but are NSString formats for iOS and Java formats for Android.